# How to access a class from within a scala swing application

Tags: swing, scala

I wrote a swing application and want to create inside it an object of class Alignment. But when I am trying to do this, I am getting this error message: "cannot resolve symbol Alignment". Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
package scala.swing
package test

import event._

object Pite extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    val seq1Label = new Label("Insert First Sequence")
    val seq2Label = new Label("Insert Second Sequence")
    val seq1 = new TextArea("Input")
    val seq2 = new TextArea("Input")
    var gap = new ComboBox(List(1,2,3,4)) { makeEditable() }
    var scoringMatrix = new ComboBox(List("BLOSUM62.txt","BLOSUM50.txt","BLOSUM100.txt"))
    val button = new Button("RUN")
    val ali = new TextArea{
      text = "test"
      listenTo(button)
      reactions += {
        case ButtonClicked(`button`) =>
          val gapVal = gap.selection.item
          val seq1container = seq1.text
          val seq2container = seq2.text
          val SMcontainer = scoringMatrix.selection.item
          val proteins = new Alignment(seq1container,seq2container,gapVal,SMcontainer)
          text = proteins.aligning

      }
    }
    contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) { contents.append(seq1Label,seq1,seq2Label,seq2,scoringMatrix,gap,ali,button) }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import it, because there is no `Alignment` class in `scala.swing` or in `scala.swing.event` (there is an [*object* `scala.swing.Alignment`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/scala-swing/#scala.swing.Alignment$), though).